# Return Index of an Element in an Array Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, indexing, find

I have an array prLst that is a list of integers. The integers are not sorted, because their position in the array represents a particular column on a spreadsheet.  I want to know how I find a particular integer in the array, and return its index.

There does not seem to be any resource on showing me how without turning the array into a range on the worksheet. This seems a bit complicated.  Is this just not possible with VBA?

Comment: For getting reverse index from Array. Please refer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73700589/get-the-reverse-index-of-a-value-from-array-in-vba

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
Dim pos, arr, val

arr=Array(1,2,4,5)
val = 4

pos=Application.Match(val, arr, False)

if not iserror(pos) then
   Msgbox val & " is at position " & pos
else
   Msgbox val & " not found!"
end if
```

Updated to show using Match (with .Index) to find a value in a dimension of a two-dimensional array:

```
Dim arr(1 To 10, 1 To 2)
Dim x

For x = 1 To 10
    arr(x, 1) = x
    arr(x, 2) = 11 - x
Next x

Debug.Print Application.Match(3, Application.Index(arr, 0, 1), 0)
Debug.Print Application.Match(3, Application.Index(arr, 0, 2), 0)
```

---

EDIT: it's worth illustrating here what @ARich pointed out in the comments - that using `Index()` to slice an array has horrible performance if you're doing it in a loop.

In testing (code below) the Index() approach is almost 2000-fold slower than using a nested loop.

```
Sub PerfTest()

    Const VAL_TO_FIND As String = "R1800:C8"
    Dim a(1 To 2000, 1 To 10)
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, t

    For r = 1 To 2000
        For c = 1 To 10
            a(r, c) = "R" & r & ":C" & c
        Next c
    Next r

    t = Timer
    Debug.Print FindLoop(a, VAL_TO_FIND), Timer - t
    ' >> 0.00781 sec

     t = Timer
    Debug.Print FindIndex(a, VAL_TO_FIND), Timer - t
    ' >> 14.18 sec

End Sub

Function FindLoop(arr, val) As Boolean
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        If arr(r, c) = val Then
            FindLoop = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next c
    Next r
End Function

Function FindIndex(arr, val)
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(val, Application.Index(arr, r, 0), 0)) Then
            FindIndex = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

Comment: and it works ! +1 I really didn't know that one could use that Match match method on a VBA array !

Comment: Many of the Excel worksheet functions have a similar form available via Application.WorksheetFunction.[FunctionName]  Note that if you drop the WorksheetFunction part (as in my example) then the function's return value can then be tested using IsError(). If you include the WorksheetFunction part then (eg) where Match() doesn't find a match it will throw an error which you'll need to catch using an error handler.

Comment: Neat! Does match also work on multi-dimensional arrays as well?

Comment: I used this function for another program I am writing, and for some reason I am getting the type mismatch error, even though the first value is an integer and the second value is an array containing integers.  Is there a reason why this would occur?

Comment: @H3lue Hard to say what your problem is without actual code. Plus you don't even mention which version you're trying to use...

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry to drudge this up after such a long time... I just wanted to point out to future readers that in some testing I did, to return a "row" reference like the `Match/Index` method above does, it's significantly faster to use a regular `Do While` loop (about 530 percent faster). The method outlined above is still really useful in certain situations, but if time is of the essence, I recommend using a loop.

Comment: I should also mention that I only tested the `Match/Index` method on a 2D array; I did not test the `Match` example on a 1D array as shown above.

Comment: Yes, it's not a performance hack.  I don't think it's any faster on the 1d array.

Comment: Is there a way to use the Match function with some error tolerance? I would like to use this for finding the index of an element in an array of floating numbers.

Answer (score 5):

array of variants:

```
    Public Function GetIndex(ByRef iaList() As Variant, ByVal value As Variant) As Long

    Dim i As Long

     For i = LBound(iaList) To UBound(iaList)
      If value = iaList(i) Then
       GetIndex = i
       Exit For
      End If
     Next i

    End Function
```

a fastest version for integers (as pref tested below)

```
    Public Function GetIndex(ByRef iaList() As Integer, ByVal value As Integer) As Integer
     Dim i As Integer

     For i = LBound(iaList) To UBound(iaList)
      If iaList(i) = value Then: GetIndex = i: Exit For:
     Next i

    End Function

' a snippet, replace myList and myValue to your varible names: (also have not tested)
```

---

a snippet, lets test the assumption the passing by reference as argument means something.  (the answer is no) to use it replace myList and myValue to your variable names:

```
  Dim found As Integer, foundi As Integer ' put only once
  found = -1
  For foundi = LBound(myList) To UBound(myList):
   If myList(foundi) = myValue Then
    found = foundi: Exit For
   End If
  Next
  result = found
```

to prove the point I have made some benchmarks

here are the results:

```
---------------------------
Milliseconds
---------------------------
result0: 5 ' just empty loop

result1: 2702  ' function variant array

result2: 1498  ' function integer array

result3: 2511 ' snippet variant array

result4: 1508 ' snippet integer array

result5: 58493 ' excel function Application.Match on variant array

result6: 136128 ' excel function Application.Match on integer array
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

a module:

```
Public Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If

    Public Function GetIndex1(ByRef iaList() As Variant, ByVal value As Variant) As Long

    Dim i As Long

     For i = LBound(iaList) To UBound(iaList)
      If value = iaList(i) Then
       GetIndex = i
       Exit For
      End If
     Next i

    End Function


'maybe a faster variant for integers

    Public Function GetIndex2(ByRef iaList() As Integer, ByVal value As Integer) As Integer
     Dim i As Integer

     For i = LBound(iaList) To UBound(iaList)
      If iaList(i) = value Then: GetIndex = i: Exit For:
     Next i

    End Function

' a snippet, replace myList and myValue to your varible names: (also have not tested)



    Public Sub test1()
     Dim i As Integer

     For i = LBound(iaList) To UBound(iaList)
      If iaList(i) = value Then: GetIndex = i: Exit For:
     Next i

    End Sub


Sub testTimer()

Dim myList(500) As Variant, myValue As Variant
Dim myList2(500) As Integer, myValue2 As Integer
Dim n

For n = 1 To 500
myList(n) = n
Next

For n = 1 To 500
myList2(n) = n
Next

myValue = 100
myValue2 = 100


Dim oPM
Set oPM = New PerformanceMonitor
Dim result0 As Long
Dim result1 As Long
Dim result2 As Long
Dim result3 As Long
Dim result4 As Long
Dim result5 As Long
Dim result6 As Long

Dim t As Long

Dim a As Long

a = 0
Dim i
't = GetTickCount
oPM.StartCounter
For i = 1 To 1000000

Next
result0 = oPM.TimeElapsed() '  GetTickCount - t

a = 0

't = GetTickCount
oPM.StartCounter
For i = 1 To 1000000
a = GetIndex1(myList, myValue)
Next
result1 = oPM.TimeElapsed()
'result1 = GetTickCount - t


a = 0

't = GetTickCount
oPM.StartCounter
For i = 1 To 1000000
a = GetIndex2(myList2, myValue2)
Next
result2 = oPM.TimeElapsed()
'result2 = GetTickCount - t



a = 0

't = GetTickCount

oPM.StartCounter
Dim found As Integer, foundi As Integer ' put only once
For i = 1 To 1000000
found = -1
For foundi = LBound(myList) To UBound(myList):
 If myList(foundi) = myValue Then
  found = foundi: Exit For
 End If
Next
a = found
Next
result3 = oPM.TimeElapsed()
'result3 = GetTickCount - t



a = 0

't = GetTickCount

oPM.StartCounter
For i = 1 To 1000000
found = -1
For foundi = LBound(myList2) To UBound(myList2):
 If myList2(foundi) = myValue2 Then
  found = foundi: Exit For
 End If
Next
a = found
Next
result4 = oPM.TimeElapsed()
'result4 = GetTickCount - t


a = 0

't = GetTickCount
oPM.StartCounter
For i = 1 To 1000000
a = pos = Application.Match(myValue, myList, False)
Next
result5 = oPM.TimeElapsed()
'result5 = GetTickCount - t



a = 0

't = GetTickCount
oPM.StartCounter
For i = 1 To 1000000
a = pos = Application.Match(myValue2, myList2, False)
Next
result6 = oPM.TimeElapsed()
'result6 = GetTickCount - t


MsgBox "result0: " & result0 & vbCrLf & "result1: " & result1 & vbCrLf & "result2: " & result2 & vbCrLf & "result3: " & result3 & vbCrLf & "result4: " & result4 & vbCrLf & "result5: " & result5 & vbCrLf & "result6: " & result6, , "Milliseconds"
End Sub
```

a class named PerformanceMonitor

```
Option Explicit

Private Type LARGE_INTEGER
    lowpart As Long
    highpart As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceCounter Lib "kernel32" (lpPerformanceCount As LARGE_INTEGER) As Long
Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceFrequency Lib "kernel32" (lpFrequency As LARGE_INTEGER) As Long

Private m_CounterStart As LARGE_INTEGER
Private m_CounterEnd As LARGE_INTEGER
Private m_crFrequency As Double

Private Const TWO_32 = 4294967296# ' = 256# * 256# * 256# * 256#

Private Function LI2Double(LI As LARGE_INTEGER) As Double
Dim Low As Double
    Low = LI.lowpart
    If Low < 0 Then
        Low = Low + TWO_32
    End If
    LI2Double = LI.highpart * TWO_32 + Low
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Dim PerfFrequency As LARGE_INTEGER
    QueryPerformanceFrequency PerfFrequency
    m_crFrequency = LI2Double(PerfFrequency)
End Sub

Public Sub StartCounter()
    QueryPerformanceCounter m_CounterStart
End Sub

Property Get TimeElapsed() As Double
Dim crStart As Double
Dim crStop As Double
    QueryPerformanceCounter m_CounterEnd
    crStart = LI2Double(m_CounterStart)
    crStop = LI2Double(m_CounterEnd)
    TimeElapsed = 1000# * (crStop - crStart) / m_crFrequency
End Property
```

Comment: I think the bad performance is from using variant as arguments. 
because of a prefetcher effect. i.e. if all memory can be read ahead. like all variables are same and read in order it performs well. if it jumps around in memory positions using references might work slower. each time it hops through a reference it decreases performance by o(1). for many references it is like (o(1)+o(1)+o(1)+o(1))*nloop.

Comment: variant is an encapsulation format. ole objects like bstr and safe array are usually references outside a process in system memory. and allocated dynamically. in different positions in memory. and a safe array easily can be an array of references. and variants also might be a reference to a reference. so it should be slow by definition.
i guess the excel functions are hack the system around and optimized for this type of issue and to be faster somehow ignore few references and checks when it is possible

Comment: i guess maybe it might be work faster if it would use several references less. like if arguments would be simple of type like integer. and variables would be not references like array byref. but byval for them to be a local copy and not a reference (change the argument type from variant to integer, and byref to byval) also maybe to not use  function rather a snippet in each place

Comment: I have made pef test. actually the performance is very good. because using the loop and not using the excel function. the pref testing reveals also that there is reference access cost per function for the array
and also for each variant in loop. also it seems like the excel's match does some copying of data and maybe convertion to Range. thta is expensive in terms of performance

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public function GetIndex(byref iaList() as integer, byval iInteger as integer) as integer

dim i as integer

 for i=lbound(ialist) to ubound(ialist)
  if iInteger=ialist(i) then
   GetIndex=i
   exit for
  end if
 next i

end function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
Option Explicit

' Just a little test stub. 
Sub Tester()

    Dim pList(500) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To UBound(pList)

        pList(i) = 500 - i

    Next i

    MsgBox "Value 18 is at array position " & FindInArray(pList, 18) & "."
    MsgBox "Value 217 is at array position " & FindInArray(pList, 217) & "."
    MsgBox "Value 1001 is at array position " & FindInArray(pList, 1001) & "."

End Sub

Function FindInArray(pList() As Integer, value As Integer)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FoundValueLocation As Integer

    FoundValueLocation = -1

    For i = 0 To UBound(pList)

        If pList(i) = value Then

            FoundValueLocation = i
            Exit For

        End If

    Next i

    FindInArray = FoundValueLocation

End Function
```

Comment: loop to find a value?

Answer (score 0):

Taking care of whether the array starts at zero or one.
Also, when position 0 or 1 is returned by the function, making sure that the same is not confused as True or False returned by the function.

```
Function array_return_index(arr As Variant, val As Variant, Optional array_start_at_zero As Boolean = True) As Variant

Dim pos
pos = Application.Match(val, arr, False)

If Not IsError(pos) Then
    If array_start_at_zero = True Then
        pos = pos - 1
        'initializing array at 0
    End If
   array_return_index = pos
Else
   array_return_index = False
End If

End Function

Sub array_return_index_test()
Dim pos, arr, val

arr = Array(1, 2, 4, 5)
val = 1

'When array starts at zero
pos = array_return_index(arr, val)
If IsNumeric(pos) Then
MsgBox "Array starting at 0; Value found at : " & pos
Else
MsgBox "Not found"
End If

'When array starts at one
pos = array_return_index(arr, val, False)
If IsNumeric(pos) Then
MsgBox "Array starting at 1; Value found at : " & pos
Else
MsgBox "Not found"
End If



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'To return the position of an element within any-dimension array  
'Returns 0 if the element is not in the array, and -1 if there is an error  
Public Function posInArray(ByVal itemSearched As Variant, ByVal aArray As Variant) As Long  
Dim pos As Long, item As Variant  

posInArray = -1  
If IsArray(aArray) Then  
    If not IsEmpty(aArray) Then  
        pos = 1  
        For Each item In aArray  
            If itemSearched = item Then  
                posInArray = pos  
                Exit Function  
            End If  
            pos = pos + 1  
        Next item  
        posInArray = 0  
    End If  
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The only (& even though cumbersome but yet expedient / relatively quick) way I can do this, is to concatenate the any-dimensional array, and reduce it to 1 dimension, with "/[column number]//\|" as the delimiter.

& use a single-cell result multiple lookupall macro function on the this 1-d column.

& then index match to pull out the positions. (usuing multiple find match)

That way you get all matching occurrences of the element/string your looking for, in the original any-dimension array, and their positions. In one cell.

Wish I could write a macro / function for this entire process. It would save me more fuss.

Comment: I have yet to write a macro code which does this: http://www.ni.com/example/27269/en/

Searching a 2D Array for Multiple Matches
This example shows how to search for a specified value in a 2D array. The VI uses a For Loop to iterate through each element of the 2D array. Whenever LabVIEW finds an element that equals the search value, LabVIEW adds the indices of the element to a separate array and then stores these indices in a shift register for the remaining iterations of the loop. This VI finds every element in the array that matches the search value.