# Excel VBA - How to search array and return value?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have some data that looks like this (starting in A1):

```
Batman
Carl Reiner
Ford
Sushi
```

But I have a two dimensional array, storing those names, and their type:

```
Dim Names()
ReDim Names(4,1)
Names(0,0) = "Batman"
Names(0,1) = "Superhero"
Names(1,0) = "Carl Reiner"
Names(1,1) = "Comedian"
Names(2,0) = "Ford"
Names(2,1) = "Car Manufacturer"
Names(3,0) = "Sushi"
Names(3,1) = "Food"
```

Now, I would like to loop through column A and replace those data points with their equivalent type.  I thought there would be a relatively simple way to essentially search Names(x,0) for "Batman" then just replace it with Names(x,1).  What's the best way to do so?

I found somewhere that you could possibly use Vlookup with this, so I tried this, to no avail:

```
Evaluate(WorksheetFunction.Vlookup("A1",Names,1,False)
```

With my thought being it would look for "Batman" and return the value in Names in the "1" dimension...But that keeps giving me an error (Type 13 Mismatch).

Thanks for any ideas/help!

edit: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031416/return-index-of-an-element-in-an-array-excel-vba) post and seem to be getting somewhere with `Application.Match("A1",Application.Index(Names,0,1),0)` which returns the position of "A1" in the array.  Now I just need to return the offset and get the "1" position of that...

Edit 2: I think I got it.  Using MATCH to find the position of "A1" then just use the array to find it:

`Names(Application.Match("A1",Application.Index(Names,0,1),0),1)`

So, when A1 is Batman, it finds that position in the index, then it finds the equivalent return in the second dimension. 
(Sorry for the lack of semantics, I don't have a very good idea of how to refer to this, so please let me know if I can clarify).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this would be easier using a Dictionary.

```
Sub testing()
    Dim dic As Object
    Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    With dic
        .Add "Batman", "Superhero"
        .Add "Carl Reiner", "Comedian"
        .Add "Ford", "Car Manufacturer"
    End With

    MsgBox "Batman is a " & dic.Item("Batman")

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes! That is fantastic.  Works perfectly, and will help me with a bunch of other macros where I have some convoluted uses of Arrays.  Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to use worksheet functions, you have to put the data into a worksheet (e.g. a column or pair of columns) instead of an array.  This is pretty easy to do, though, and you can use a different worksheet, or even another workbook, and there are solutions to hide these, so your users don't have to see that data cluttering the other worksheets.

Comment: I have thought about that (putting the stuff into a separate worksheet, and using regular Vlookup from there), but I was curious about arrays because if I put this in some external worksheet, I have to have the sheet referenced in my code, open it, run the lookup.  The bigger pain comes from if one of my data points (in column A) is NOT in the array - I write prompts to add it to that external sheet, save, etc. I can do that, but was curious if there's a way to do this bypassing external stuff and just using an array.

Comment: You can create a hidden and temporary worksheet in the same workbook, populate it with the array contents, then run worksheet functions, then delete the hidden temporary worksheet (or leave it there hidden and let it be saved along with the other worksheets).

Comment: yeah, I have used that idea with other macros, but am trying to learn more about VBA to where I can A) cut down on the code, B) reduce the need for such sheets, and C) have the macro run quicker.  Thanks though for the help!