# Return Index of an Element of an Array within Error Tolerance in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, indexing

Is there a simple way, not looping through an array, but using a function in VBA, something like Application.Match(val, arr, False|true), to find the index of a element in an array of floating numbers, within some tolerance? By within tolerance, I mean if the element is within the range of the target value plus and minus the tolerance, i.e. small positive number.

Trimax comments that this is a duplicate of [another index return question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031416/return-index-of-an-element-in-an-array-excel-vba). This is not the case and the answer to that question certainly does not answer my question, even though these two questions are related. That question asks for the index of an integer which can be matched exactly, while mine asks for the index of a of a number within nonzero tolerance of a target, rather than exactly equal. So that answer does not apply.

Comment: If you have them in one column you can try conditional formatting `Cell Value + between + =3.597 + =3.599`, color them red, then apply AutoFilter on color red, and use `variant = .Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to get the array

Comment: What's wrong with looping?  Should be simple enough to abstract the logic to a function.

Comment: @Trimax: No it is not. Please read the question carefully. That question asks for the index of an integer which can be matched exactly. I am asking for the index of a of a number within nonzero tolerance of a target, rather than exactly equal.

Comment: @Hans you're right, sorry.  I've deleted the comment.

Comment: @Trimax: Good to clear that up. May I ask if you put the claim "the question may already have an answer ..." in the question? If so, would you please delete that claim up there as well? Just in case, did you down vote my question on the suspicion of duplication? If so, would you mind canceling that downvote, or would you care to explain the downvote?  Thank you.

Comment: @TimWilliams: There is nothing wrong with the loop other than it is not within the set of answer I am seeking. There is nothing wrong writing all code from two binary logic operations together with integer arithmetics building from 1+1=2 or even with mathematical logic, we just need 1+1=2. But since there are already builtin function  of I would like to utilize the existing library as much as I can. Of course, if it turns out there is no library functions, preferably one or two liners, that is simpler to use than a loop, then I will have to resort to loops.

Comment: Not sure about the downvote, but finding ways to process multiple values without looping is sometimes necessary, and usually faster to work within a much smaller subset (+1)

Answer (score 0):

As an exercise I selected an array of random floating numbers:

`3.5, 3.1, 3.3, 3.9, 3.2, 3.1, 3.7, 3.5, 3.7`

and arbitrary MIN (`3.3`) and MAX (`3.7`) limits.

I also replaced conditional formatting with AutoFilter for the same result

.

The code will create a new sheet then

- place the array values in column 1
- create a new column with indexes (row numbers)
- apply an AutoFilter to display only floating numbers between MIN and MAX
- capture all visible indexes from column 2
- remove temporary sheet and display a message

---

```
Option Explicit

'Place the code in a new module (from the menu: Insert -> Module)

Public Sub getIndexes()

    Const MIN       As String = "3.3"
    Const MAX       As String = "3.7"
    Const FLOATS    As String = "3.5, 3.1, 3.3, 3.9, 3.2, 3.1, 3.7, 3.5, 3.7"

    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr As Variant, arrMax As Long
    Dim indx As Variant, c1 As Range, c2 As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = getNewWorkSheet("TestIndexes")
    arr = Split(FLOATS, ", ")
    arrMax = UBound(arr) + 1
    With ws
        Set c1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(arrMax, 1))
        Set c2 = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(arrMax, 2))
        c1 = Application.Transpose(arr)
        c2.Formula = "=ROW()"
        c1.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                      Criteria1:=">=" & MIN, _
                      Operator:=xlAnd, _
                      Criteria2:="<=" & MAX
        c2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy .Cells(arrMax + 2, 1)
        indx = .Range(.Cells(arrMax + 2, 1), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1)).Value2
    End With
    removeWorkSheet ws.Name
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    arr = Join(Application.Transpose(indx), ",   ")
    MsgBox "Indexes of values between  " & MIN & "  and  " & MAX & ":   " & arr
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function getNewWorkSheet(ByVal wsName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim thisWS As Worksheet, activeWS As String
    activeWS = ActiveSheet.Name
    removeWorkSheet wsName
    Set thisWS = Worksheets.Add(Sheets(1))
    thisWS.Name = wsName
    Worksheets(activeWS).Activate
    Set getNewWorkSheet = thisWS
End Function

Public Sub removeWorkSheet(ByVal wsName As String)
    Dim thisWS As Worksheet
    For Each thisWS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If thisWS.Name = wsName Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            thisWS.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Result:

[image: random array] [image: output]

.

If you're working with a large array the algorithm can be optimized for performance

Let me know if you need more details

Comment: The operation should all be accomplished within VBA not using a GUI. I suppose you could substitute the GUI invoking process with  a VBA line. Hopefully it is not too cumbersome.

Comment: I used the GUI for illustration only but there are specific VBA elements to be used like `Range.FormatConditions(formatConditionId)`. If you can provide more specifics about your particular task I can work on some examples

Comment: I see. There is not much more specifics than the following. There is an array of floating numbers and I would like to find the index of the array element that is within a pre-specified distance (error tolerance) from a given number. That distance is smaller than the minimum of the difference between any neighboring numbers in the array.