# Excel VBA: Get Minimum out of 1 Dimension in Multi Dimensional Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

for work, I need to adjust some prewritten VBA code. But I am rather a beginner, thus it is quite challenging for me.

The code creates a 2D array called Targets. It spans by (a variable number of ) KPIs and for each KPI the values for 10 years (fix number). E.g.:

**KPI 1** year_1 year_2 ... year_10
**KPI 2** year_1 year_2 ... year_10
...   ...    ....   ... .....   ...    ....   ... .....   ...    ...
**KPI n**  year_1 year_2 ... year_10

I now need to calculate the minimum per KPI line (1D array).

My ugly working code: 

`WorksheetFunction.Min(Targets(k, 0), Targets(k , 1), Targets(k, 2), Targets(k, 3), Targets(k , 4), Targets(k , 5), Targets(k, 6), Targets(k, 7), Targets(k, 8), Targets(k , 9))`

Where k is directing to the correct KPI.

How can I make it work such that it basically takes the entire line without me having to direct the code to each specific cell? (e.g. Targets (k,:) or Targets (k, 0 to 9))

Bonus question: Some values within these arrays are zero as they are tbd. Those are supposed to be excluded from the minimum. So I need the Minimum > zero. Can you figure that out too?

It probably is super easy. But I cannot seem to make it work.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031416/return-index-of-an-element-in-an-array-excel-vba/7031744#7031744

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub this()
    Dim Targets As Variant
    Dim minValuePerRow As String
    minValuePerRow = ""
    Targets = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange
    For i = LBound(Targets, 1) To UBound(Targets, 1)
        For j = LBound(Targets, 2) To UBound(Targets, 2)
            If (Targets(i, j) <> 0 Or Targets(i, j) <> "") And minValuePerRow = "" Then minValuePerRow = Targets(i, j)
            If Targets(i, j) <> 0 And Targets(i, j) < minValuePerRow Then
                 minValuePerRow = Targets(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
        Debug.Print ; i
        Debug.Print ; minValuePerRow
        minValuePerRow = ""
    Next i
End Sub
```

*EDIT*

Reworked and tested it. This should be more than plenty to help you adjust to your needs.

Comment: Although this works, it has a time of O(n^2). Try implementing a different sort (Like quicksort or mergesort) to significantly speed the processs.

Comment: @Jsleshem I wasnt going to get too complicated for something so simple. He did say he was working with arrays....

Comment: fair, I understand

Comment: You sir, are my hero! Thank you so much. I was able to adjust it accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address the second part of your question about excluding zeros but...

Given a 2-D array (such as you might get from a worksheet range using `Value`), you can use Application.Index to get a "slice" of that array:

[image]

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim arr, slice
    arr = Range("A1:C3").Value

    'get a "row"
    slice = Application.Index(arr, 1, 0)
    Debug.Print Join(slice, "-") '>> 1-2-3

    'get a "column" (note use of Transpose here)
    slice = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(arr, 0, 1))
    Debug.Print Join(slice, "-") '>> 1-4-7
    'col 2...
    slice = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(arr, 0, 2))
    Debug.Print Join(slice, "-") '>> 2-5-8

    Debug.Print Application.Min(slice) '>> 2


End Sub
```

Worth noting that the performance of this approach is kind of bad though: [Return Index of an Element in an Array Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031416/return-index-of-an-element-in-an-array-excel-vba/7031744#7031744)

Answer (score 0):

If the array size is too large, you'll find this to be very slow.  It uses the Evaluate method to return the minimum for each row.  However, you'll notice that I've included a function that makes those target values available to the Evaluate Method. Also, you'll notice that Targets is declared at the module level.

```
Dim Targets As Variant

Public Function Values() As Variant
    Values = Targets
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim i As Long

    Targets = Range("A1:J10").Value

    For i = LBound(Targets, 1) To UBound(Targets)
        Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("MIN(IF(INDEX(Values()," & i & ",0)>0,INDEX(Values()," & i & ",0)))")
    Next i
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!