# How To Rank A Multi Dimensional Array In VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm embarrassed I couldn't find this answer on my own, but if I have a multi-dimensional VBA array, and wish to use the `Rank/Large/Small` function on a single dimension, how is that executed?

Example:

```
Dim Arr(1, 2) As Integer

    Arr(0, 0) = 1
    Arr(0, 1) = 2
    Arr(0, 2) = -1
    Arr(1, 0) = 100
    Arr(1, 1) = 40
    Arr(1, 2) = 60
```

Here's a visual illustration:

[image]

If I want the largest number in the Arr(0, x) field (which would be 2), how is that executed? For the largest in the Arr(1,x) field I would expect 100.

I've tried:

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Arr(, 2), 1)` this errors
`Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(Arr(1, 2), 1)` this gives just that array on that postion.

I've googled:

- ranking multi-dimensional arrays
- how to rank a single dimension an array
- rank one dimension in array

No luck. I could probably find it, but I'm also hoping I might get a -3 ranking on this weak question so I get can delete it and earn the SO "humiliation" badge (or whatever it's called).

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031416/return-index-of-an-element-in-an-array-excel-vba/7031744#7031744

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to peel out one of the ranks with the worksheet's Index function.

```
Dim Arr(1, 2) As Integer

Arr(0, 0) = 1
Arr(0, 1) = 2
Arr(0, 2) = -1
Arr(1, 0) = 100
Arr(1, 1) = 40
Arr(1, 2) = 60

Debug.Print Application.Large(Application.Index(Arr, 0, 2), 1)
```

Index is used as *all the 'rows' (0) in the second 'column' (2)*. Between 2 and 40 in the second rank, 40 is the largest.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Took me a second to figure out what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on Jeeped answer (as it took me a couple minutes to figure out):

With

```
Dim Arr(1, 2) As Integer

Arr(0, 0) = 1
Arr(0, 1) = 2
Arr(0, 2) = -1
Arr(1, 0) = 100
Arr(1, 1) = 40
Arr(1, 2) = 60
```

Here is how you would return the top ranked member for the Arr(0,x):
`Application.Large(Application.Index(Arr, 1, 0), 1)` **Returns 2**

For the second set Arr(1,x):
`Application.Large(Application.Index(Arr, 2, 0), 1)` **Returns 100**

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop like

```
Dim large As Double

large = arr(row, 0)

For i = 1 To numberOfColumns
  If (arr(row, i) > large) Then
    large = arr(row, i)
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: Yea but this would be incredibly less efficient. If you’re ranking thousands of members or continuously doing this for generating random numbers millions of times (my specific purpose), this is much much slower.