# Index Lookup Across Sheets; Slow Speeds (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, optimization

[This is more an optimization question than an issue with the code; is there a better place to post this?]

I'm trying to (in the simplest terms) use a macro in 3 columns to INDEX a value, with the INDEX referencing a table in another sheet (same workbook). If it finds a value, it outputs the result; if it doesn't it outputs "NOT FOUND".

My issue is that on ~1000 lines of code it's already taking ~7 seconds to run. I previously had the code in 3 separate loops for each column but cut it down to one loop to help speed it up, but it's still quite slow. For reference,  I'll have to run this code on anywhere from 200K lines to 900K, depending on the month.

I've used arrays in much more taxing code and it barely takes a couple of seconds with those, so I feel like it's something simple I'm missing/forgetting; I've also heard that worksheet functions in VBA are un-optimized which could be it (never used index in VBA before), but that might be misinformation.

***Note:*** 
I've shortened the code as much as possible to make finding the core issue easier; The code itself works 100% correctly, it is just slow. I've put my declared variables into comments with their type, and only shown the lookup process for 1 column (the lookup is basically identical for the other two columns).

```
Sub RefreshData()

Call TurnEverythingOff 'Turns off screenupdating, calculations, events, etc.
On Error GoTo Skip

'Variables that are declared (Dim'd) [Put into comments to save space]
    'SR_Data is the start row of data [Long]
    'ER_Data is the end row of data [Long]
    'SC_Data is the start col of data [String]
    'EC_Data is the end col of data [String]
    'Range/Array_Data are the respective range/array of the above 4 values [Set Range/Variant]
    '*****_Col is the numerical value representing the columns for lookup etc. [Long]
    '*****_Table is the range that the INDEX/Lookup will view (but in another sheet) [Range]
    'Array****Value is to hold the cell string [String]
    'Section_DNE is for when values aren't found in INDEX/Lookup [String]

'[MAPPING] Actually performs the lookup/logic
With Data 'Made the sheet codename this in VBA editor
.Activate
    ER_Data = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set Range_Data = Range(SC_Data & SR_Data & ":" & EC_Data & ER_Data)
        Array_Data = Range_Data.Value





'Looking for assistance in speeding **THIS** section up.
    For Each DataCell In Range_Data.Columns(1).Cells
            'Debug.Print (DataCell.Address)
            With Application.WorksheetFunction

                'Defines the value in the cell that will need to be looked for
                ArrayDisciplineValue = Array_Data(DataCell.Row - SR_Data + 1, Discipline_Col)
                ArrayFundNameValue = Array_Data(DataCell.Row - SR_Data + 1, FundName_Col)                

            Mapping.Activate 'Sheet Codename, sheet contains tables for lookup

            'For Discipline Lookup
                On Error GoTo ErrorHandle1
                ArrayDisciplineValue = _
                    .Index(Discipline_Table, _
                    .Match(ArrayFundNameValue, Discipline_Table.Columns(1), 0), _
                    2)

            Data.Activate 'Sheet Codename

                'For Discipline Mapping
                Array_Data(DataCell.Row - SR_Data + 1, Discipline_Col) = ArrayDisciplineValue

            End With
    Next DataCell
End With







Range_Data.Value = Array_Data

ErrorHandle1:
'For when the INDEX LOOKUP fails to find the value...
ArrayDisciplineValue = Section_DNE
Resume Next

Skip:
Call TurnEverythingOn
End Sub
```

Expected Result: Takes ~1s for 1000 rows (as it's in an array it should be faster, no?)

Actual Result: Takes ~7s for 1000 rows

Scaling it up to 200,000 rows.

Comment: Comment out `Mapping.Activate` and `Data.Activate`  Note Index/Match work much faster *when the data is on a worksheet* - in this case performance will be *worse* performing the lookup against an array.  Using an array is the answer when you have a lot of reads/writes to/from the worksheet, since it allows you to batch up those operations: it doesn't speed up everything.  For more see here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031416/return-index-of-an-element-in-an-array-excel-vba/7031744#7031744

Comment: So is the ideal scenario that I move the mapping tables to the same sheet as the data (if I want to keep my code the same)? Is there any way to keep my code fast and the mapping tables on a different sheet; from the link you provided, the application.match/index approach didn't work as it was much slower, correct? i.e. there's no way to index/match across sheets efficiently, one should instead use Do While?

Comment: There's no need to move the mapping table - you can perform a lookup across sheets with no problem.  It's difficult to tell exactly what's going on in your code as you don't supply values for SC_Data/EC_Data

Comment: Hi Tim, I commented out the Mapping.Activate and Data.Activate; I'd previously tried it without these and it had been referencing the range on the active sheet for some reason, so I must've had something different prior that caused that. I can post the SC_Data/EC_Data etc. values if that would help, but just removing the .activate parts has sped it up significantly already! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using arrays should speed up your code -- provided that you don't continue to interact with the cells/worksheets -- and do everything (or as much of the work as possible) in memory (where the array is being stored).

You read your values into an array on this line (which is fine):

```
Array_Data = Range_Data.Value
```

But then you continue to interact with the worksheet:

```
For Each DataCell In Range_Data.Columns(1).Cells
```

And your reason for doing so seems to be so that you can access the `Row` member of `DataCell` -- which you in turn use to refer to elements at some specific index (or row) within your array.

I think you should instead use the `Lbound` and `Ubound` functions to loop over your array. These functions are designed for arrays and using them means you no longer have to interact with the spreadsheet (accessing members/cells).

I can't re-write your code fully, but hopefully something like the below can get you closer to what you want to achieve (in terms of performance/speed). Please see comments for further details. Also, I recommend that you put `Option Explicit` at the top of all modules (if you haven't already).

Last point is that your code contained a variable named `Discipline_Table`. You access its `Columns` member, so I presume it's a `range` (or something). Ideally you want to read its values into an array. Maybe read its first column into one array, and the whole range into another array (you don't seem to change their values, so reading them once before the loop should be okay in your case). That's what I do below. Otherwise, you're still interacting with some worksheet/cells inside your loop (which you want to avoid, as it's relatively slow).

```
Option Explicit

Sub RefreshData()

    'Call TurnEverythingOff 'Turns off screenupdating, calculations, events, etc.
    'On Error GoTo Skip

    'Variables that are declared (Dim'd) [Put into comments to save space]
    'SR_Data is the start row of data [Long]
    'ER_Data is the end row of data [Long]
    'SC_Data is the start col of data [String]
    'EC_Data is the end col of data [String]
    'Range/Array_Data are the respective range/array of the above 4 values [Set Range/Variant]
    '*****_Col is the numerical value representing the columns for lookup etc. [Long]
    '*****_Table is the range that the INDEX/Lookup will view (but in another sheet) [Range]
    'Array****Value is to hold the cell string [String]
    'Section_DNE is for when values aren't found in INDEX/Lookup [String]

    '[MAPPING] Actually performs the lookup/logic
    With Data 'Made the sheet codename this in VBA editor
    '.Activate
        Dim SC_Data As String
        Dim EC_Data As String

        Dim SR_Data As Long

        Dim ER_Data As Long
        ER_Data = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim Range_Data As Range
        ' I added a . before your Range. Presume you wanted it to relate to your Data sheet
        ' rather than an implicit reference to ActiveSheet
        Set Range_Data = Range(SC_Data & SR_Data & ":" & EC_Data & ER_Data)

        Dim Array_Data() As Variant
        Array_Data = Range_Data.Value
    End With

    Dim firstColumnOfDisciplineTable() As Variant
    firstColumnOfDisciplineTable = Discipline_Table.Columns(1).Value

    Dim disciplineTable() As Variant
    disciplineTable = Discipline_Table.Value2

    Dim rowIndex As Long

    Dim Discipline_Col As Long
    Dim FundName_col As Long



    ' 1 here (below) refers to the first dimension - AKA "rows".
    ' If we passed 2 as the second argument, we would get the first and last "columns" of our array
    For rowIndex = LBound(Array_Data, 1) To UBound(Array_Data, 1)

        Dim ArrayDisciplineValue As String
        ArrayDisciplineValue = Array_Data(rowIndex - SR_Data + 1, Discipline_Col)

        Dim ArrayFundNameValue As String
        ArrayFundNameValue = Array_Data(rowIndex - SR_Data + 1, FundName_col)

        ' Use Application.Match (instead of Application.WorksheetFunction.Match)
        ' so that if you do get an error value, you can safely assign it to a variable of type Variant
        ' without getting an error at runtime.
        ' This saves you having to use On Error GoTo ... handling.
        Dim matchResult As Variant
        matchResult = Application.Match(ArrayFundNameValue, firstColumnOfDisciplineTable, 0)

        If IsNumeric(matchResult) Then
            ArrayDisciplineValue = Application.Index(disciplineTable, matchResult, 2)
        Else
            Dim Section_DNE As String
            ArrayDisciplineValue = Section_DNE
        End If

        'For Discipline Mapping
        Array_Data(rowIndex - SR_Data + 1, Discipline_Col) = ArrayDisciplineValue

    Next rowIndex

    Range_Data.Value = Array_Data


'Skip:
'Call TurnEverythingOn
End Sub
```

---

- I declared `disciplineTable() As Variant`, as we're reading values from a spreadsheet; the types of which could be anything in theory (string, number, error, etc.). The `()` means we can only assign a multi-cell area/range (rather than a single cell) to the array -- which is good because the rest of the code expects an array.
- There isn't any difference between `Range.Value2` and `Range.Value` in most cases. You could probably use `Range.Value` (or even just `Range` in this context which would  call `.Value` implicitly) if you wanted -- unless you're dealing with currencies and dates and want to prevent them from being converted to `Double`s.
- Not sure why `Lbound` and `Ubound` aren't working for you, but seems like you have a workaround with your start row and end row. Just be careful that arrays read from ranges are 1-based, so you should ensure the index you specify is also 1-based. The index also needs to be relative to the array.

Comment: I didn't even consider reading the table into an array; that's a great suggestion, thanks! I'll try and edit my code with your suggestions, but one question; why do you have disciplineTable() As Variant, and what is .Value2 as opposed to .Value? I don't seem to understand the use of that section. Also, I attempted to re-do the code and with LBound and UBound I'm getting stuck where RowIndex = 1 then the loop stops (but I can just use SR_Data and ER_Data to get the same effect so it's fine!).

Comment: I've reduced it down to ~15 seconds due to your suggestions, so thanks :)

Comment: @DoogieB, sorry for late reply, have edited my answer to respond to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here i instance an object who will get all the cells
that way you optimze , when you run a loop calling a Property/Method
the vba will call that properties and methods everytime the loop become a gain
when you set the object or the value , The loop become faster!

```
    Dim Allcells As Object
    Set Allcells = Range_Data.Columns(1).Cells
'Looking for assistance in speeding **THIS** section up.
    For Each DataCell In Allcells
```

Hope you enjoy the tip !