# INDEX/MATCH within Arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, indexing, match

I have a large report that I am pulling into a multi-dimensional array. I'm then using a function to remove dupes and then running various loops summarizing the data from the main array, but I am stuck on one point. I can't find a way to use INDEX/MATCH functions within arrays.

ie if I was simply using the report on the sheet I would use INDEX/MATCH to lookup column K and return the value in column G.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Just loop the array, it will not be as quick, but also not that slow.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid loops as I'm already running numerous loops and it's already within 1 very large loop, so anywhere I can save time is a benefit, but maybe there's no other easy way....

Comment: Looping is the way to go... for starters, MATCH is slower when used against an array than when used against a cell range... and `INDEX/MATCH` doesn't make sense when using arrays.

Comment: You would need to pull the column to use in the Match out of the 2d array and make it a 1d array.  That itself is slow.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, makes sense and I guess I can do it as another function with a loop. In my mind index/match seemed like the logical way to approach it as I'd do it without thinking if I was working within the sheets, but that doesn't always apply to VBA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031416/return-index-of-an-element-in-an-array-excel-vba/7031744#7031744  but performance is very bad.

Comment: I wonder if organizing your data into a dictionary of class objects, where the class contains the various data types you are summarizing, might be a faster way of doing things.

Comment: Could you edit minimal example data for better understanding? - @xceej