# Get the reverse index of a value from Array in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2019

I have an integer array.

```
Dim a as Variant
a = Array(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5)
Dim index as Integer
index = Application.Match(4,a,0) '3
```

index is 3 here. It returns the index of first occurrence of 4. But I want the last occurrence index of 4.

In python, there is rindex which returns the reverse index. I am new to vba, any similar api available in VBA?
Note: I am using Microsoft office Professional 2019
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`XMATCH()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xmatch-function-d966da31-7a6b-4a13-a1c6-5a33ed6a0312) avaibalble in O365 and Excel 2021. Try-

```
Sub ReverseMatch()
Dim a As Variant
Dim index As Integer

    a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    index = Application.XMatch(4, a, 0, -1) '-1 indicate search last to first.
    Debug.Print index

End Sub
```

You can also try below sub.

```
Sub ReverseMatch()
Dim a As Variant
Dim index As Integer, i As Integer

    a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    For i = UBound(a) To LBound(a) Step -1
        If a(i) = 4 Then
            Debug.Print i + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I am using Microsoft Office Professional 2019.
Getting "Object doesn't support this property" error

Comment: Excel-2019 doesn't have `XMATCH()` function. Its only available to Excel-365.

Comment: @usmanharoon You can try my edited codes.

Comment: Helpful & instructive to see a use of XMatch +:) Side note: I wouldn't declare `index` As Long or Integer, but as Variant to allow a check like `If Not IsError(index)` or even more speaking `If IsNumeric(index)` @Harun24h

Comment: @T.M. Thanks. If there possibility to not found the lookup value then ISERROR would be good choice.

Comment: @T.M. `FILTERXML()` is giant function. I like `FILTERXML()` very much.

Answer (score 3):

Try the next way, please:

```
Sub lastOccurrenceMatch()
   Dim a As Variant, index As Integer
    a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    index = Application.Match(CStr(4), Split(StrReverse(Join(a, "|")), "|"), 0) '2
    Debug.Print index, UBound(a) + 1 - index + 1
End Sub
```

Or a version not raising an error in case of no match:

```
Sub lastOccurrenceMatchBetter()
   Dim a As Variant, index As Variant
    a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    index = Application.Match(CStr(4), Split(StrReverse(Join(a, "|")), "|"), 0) '2
    If Not IsError(index) Then
        Debug.Print index, UBound(a) + 1 - index + 1
    Else
        Debug.Print "No any match..."
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

The next version reverses the array as it is (without join/split sequence). Just using `Index`. Just for the sake of playing with arrays:

```
Sub testMatchReverseArray()
Dim a As Variant, index As Integer, cnt As Long, col As String, arrRev()
    a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 12, 3, 4, 15)
    cnt = UBound(a) + 1
    col = Split(cells(1, cnt).Address, "$")(1)
    arrRev = Evaluate(cnt & "+1-column(A:" & col & ")") 'build the reversed columns array

    a = Application.index(Application.Transpose(a), arrRev, 0)

    Debug.Print Join(a, "|") 'just to visually see the reversed array...
    index = Application.match(4, a, 0)
    Debug.Print index, UBound(a) + 1 - index + 1
End Sub
```

Second **Edit**:

The next solution matches the initial array with one loaded with only element to be searched. Then reverse it (using `StrReverse`) and search the matching positions ("1"):

```
Sub MatchLastOccurrence()
   Dim a(), arr(), srcVar, arrMtch(), index As Integer
   
   a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 12, 3, 4, 15)
   srcVar = 4 'the array element to identify its last position
   
   arr = Array(srcVar)    
   arrMtch = Application.IfError(Application.match(a, arr, 0), 0)
    Debug.Print Join(arrMtch, "|") '1 for matching positions, zero for not matching ones
    
    index = Application.match("1", Split(StrReverse(Join(arrMtch, "|")), "|"), 0) '2
    Debug.Print index, UBound(a) + 1 - index + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, but the `StrReverse` command will not work for numbers like 10 or 12, where shifting places would change the value.

Comment: @Olle Sjögren Yup... I know it. I observed that the array in discussion contains only 1 digit elements...:)  It is the single case (I think) to be correctly reversed without iteration. Otherwise, an iteration will be necessary...

Comment: @Olle Sjögren Please, see the updated answer, the part after **Editede**. Just for the sake of playing with arrays...

Comment: Just for the sake of the art, I posted another approach via `FilterXML` to complete all the valid solutions here +:)

Comment: @Olle Sjögren Please, also see the second edit (and also the previous solution change, using a build reversed array, on the fly). Also, for the sake of playing with arrays... :)

Comment: Glad I could help with 1st edit; like your way of getting to the bottom of things. - Side note to 2nd edit: Though seeming unusual, it would suffice here to assign an *array* containing a **single** value only (i.e. the search value) to `arr`: `arr = Array(srcVar)` @FaneDuru

Comment: @T.M. Yes, you are right! I knew that the arrays to be matched do not have to be of the same size, but I did not think at an **array** with a single element, even if I should. And I overcomplicated the code because of that... Thanks! I will also adapt the code with the simpler/more compact way. But playing with array is interesting, anyhow. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative via `FilterXML()`**

Just in order to complete the valid solutions above, I demonstrate another approach via `FilterXML()` (available since vers. 2013+):

This method doesn't require to reverse the base array; instead it filters & counts all elements before the last finding (i.e. all elements that have another right neighbor with the searched value).

```
Function lastPos(arr, ByVal srch) As Long
'a) create wellformed xml string & XPath search string
    Dim xml:   xml = "<all><i>" & Join(arr, "</i><i>") & "</i></all>"
    Dim XPath: XPath = "//i[following-sibling::i[.=" & srch & "]]"
'b) Filter xml elements before finding at last position
    With Application
        Dim x: x = .FilterXML(xml, XPath)  ' << apply FilterXML()
        If IsError(x) Then                 ' no finding or 1st position = srch
            lastPos = IIf(arr(0) = srch, 1, .Count(x))
        Else
            lastPos = .Count(x) + 1        ' ordinal position number (i.e. +1)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

**Example call**

```
Dim arr:  arr  = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Dim srch: srch = 4
Debug.Print _
    "Last Position of " & srch & ": " & _
    lastPos(arr, srch)   ' ~~> last Pos of 4: 8
```

Comment: Interesting, as usually... Voted up. I was also thinking of obtaining an array of the searched number (`4`, in this case) with the same number of elements as the array to be searched for (`arr`), of course, **without iteration**. To obtain such an array of strings "4" is simple, but do you have an idea of transforming its elements in numbers. I remember that you did the reverse operation. I mean obtaining an array of strings using `Evaluate("ROW(...)")`. I do not remember how you did it, anymore... Do you remember? I like you to refresh my memory. You added somehow the null string at the end.

Comment: Maybe misunderstanding you: Did you mean how to get the reverse order of 1 to 9 by evaluation resulting e.g. in `Array(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)`? - Having defined the elements count `cnt = 9` and a virtual column character `col = Split((Columns(cnt).Address(, 0)), ":")(0)` you might try `arr = Evaluate(cnt & "+1-column(A:" & col & ")")` @FaneDuru

Comment: I forgot that in my answer I promised to find a way of building the reversed columns array, necessary to reverse the array to be processed, using `Application.index`... You 'answered' that part... :) Thanks! I was really busy and forgot about it. I was asking for something like `Array(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)`, in case of matching last occurrence of `4`, in order to post a different way of answering to the original question. I found a way in the meantime. I will adapt the previous code, using the built arran and post another way, too.