# Access to vba dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, performance, dictionary, ms-access

Is there a way to export around 500,000 individual data points from an Access table to a dictionary object in Excel VBA? My understanding is that this should translate into the same number of individual dictionary keys.

The Access table has around 2,000 rows with roughly 250 columns. Right now, I am accessing each row individually as each row represents one specific scenario, i.e., I have 2,000 scenarios. For each scenario/ row, my code pulls each of the 250 items individually and puts them into a dictionary, each item with a unique key. Later on, I use each item for calculations I am doing between dictionaries to create new dictionaries. That's why I have chosen dictionaries as the unique code seemed appropriate for my setting. I am open to use anything else than dictionaries if it speeds up the code.

Note: I previously, had the whole code based on arrays which took me even more time. The switch to dictionaries gave me a boost of roughly 25% in time savings, however, the code still takes around 3 hours. I noticed that particularly the data pulling from the access takes the most significant chunk of the time.

Also note that my code is not (!) accessing the Excel workbook at any time except at the end when it puts the results to one worksheet within the Excel file.

Any idea is much appreciated, particularly to increase the performance of data accessing process. Maybe there is a quick way to transfer all data points at one into a dictionary instead of running the process all over again each time.

I am aware of the fact that Excel VBA might not be the best solutions in the first place, but for now it's the only language I master.

The code below is pulling each item (out of 250) for one scenario (out of 2,000) individually and puts it into a dictionary.

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, strClass As String
Dim dictReturn As Object: Set dictReturn = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = 1 To 25   'i represents one of 25 individual asset classes
    For k = 2023 To (2023 + 9)
        strClass = cltClassesConning(i) & " " & k   'k represents the year for a given asset class over time
        strClassPath = strClass & "_" & j   'j represents the current scenario out of the 2,000 overall
        Dim abc: abc = return_individual(strClass, j)  'this function returns each item in a given row one after another and puts it into a dictionary: see below for function code
        If Not dictReturn.Exists(strClass) Then dictReturn.Add strClassPath, abc(strClass).Value
    Next k
Next i
```

Function as indicated above. It pulls the data from the Access database

```
Public Function return_individual(strClass As String, j As Integer) As ADODB.recordset
'-------------------------------------------------
Dim fileName As String: fileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "[name of Access database].accdb"
Dim cntName As String: cntName = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
                                    & fileName & ";Persist Security Info=False;"

Dim cnt As Object: Set cnt = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
cnt.Open cntName

Dim rs As Object: Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Dim query As String: query = "SELECT [" & strClass & "] FROM input_table WHERE Scenario=" & j & ";"

rs.Source = query
rs.ActiveConnection = cnt
rs.Open

Set return_individual = rs
'-------------------------------------------------
End Function
```

So far I tried both (1) storing the originally 500,000 data points in the Excel file itself by means of arrays and (2) storing the data points in Access pulling them individually into dictionaries. I would need a hybrid solution between arrays and dictionaries. While the former can be populated without looping (which dictionaries cannot as far as I know), the latter is unique through its keys (while arrays require more performance to pick the exact individual value).

Comment: I would start by opening the connection once and passing it as a parameter into return_individual(). Is there any pre-processing you can do in access?

Comment: I agree with @CDP1802. The main problem is that, that whenever you call your function you open another instance of connection, which takes time. I'd loop through the scenarios in one procedure/function.

Comment: Read the whole table in one query and create all the Dictionaries in a loop?  Querying each individual property seems like it would be much slower than reading a whole record at a time.

Comment: @TimWilliams, as far as i understand, one query is impossible. There's 250 columns * 2000 entries...

Comment: What's wrong with `select * from input_table where ...` ?  That seem preferable to running hundreds of `select oneColumn from input_table where...` queries.

Comment: @CDP1802 and Maciej Los I will try to follow your suggestion today. Within Access the data most likely is already as processed as it can get.

Comment: @CDP1802 and Maciej Los: Your hint saved me roughly 50% of time in running the code. Thank you. Do you have any additional suggestions that could boost performance?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for your suggestion. That's actually one of my previous trial and error steps: I used one query, stored the data either (1) in an array or (2) in a Excel worksheet. Then I looped through all 500k data points to populate my dictionary. However, the result is that this took more time than populating the dictionary accessing each data point individually directly from the orginal database in Access.

Comment: It looks like you have a 3 dimension data cube scenario,  year, class,  so you could build  3D array like data(1 to 2000, 1 to 10, 1 to 25) or since the scenarios appear to be numeric an array of dictionaries of dictionaries like data(scenario)(class)(year). Or probably the most memory efficient an array of dictionaries of arrays. It really depends on what the  processing you want to do with the data . Are the data point numeric ?

Comment: @CDP1802: You are right with your assessment regarding the dimenions of the data. And indeed, all are numeric (doubles in general). So you are basically saying to put dictionaries into a 3D array? I think I get what you are saying... right now, I am putting both (1) class name, (2) year and (3) scenario in the keys of the dictionary. The actual value is then stored in the value to this unique key. Help me out here: I do not see how using a dictionary entry with three entries (scenario, class, year) would be superior to that. At least the number of dictionary entries would not vary, does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your keys are numeric then an array is more memory efficient, if they are alpha then use a  dictionary. This build an array of dictionaries with array values in about 20 seconds for 2000 records with 250 fields.

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim dbconn As ADODB.Connection, data
    Set dbconn = DbConnect("SO_75608685.accdb")
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    'MsgBox dbConn.Version
    data = BuildCube(dbconn, 2023) ' start year
    
    ' data(scenario)(class)(yr-2022)
    MsgBox "2023 CLASS01 1 = " & data(1)("CLASS01")(1), vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")

    ' check access
    Dim rs
    Set rs = dbconn.Execute("SELECT [CLASS01 2023] FROM input_table WHERE Scenario = 1")
    MsgBox "In Access 2023 CLASS01 1 = " & rs(0)
End Sub

Function BuildCube(dbconn As ADODB.Connection, YR1 As Long) As Variant

     Dim data(1 To 2000), classDict As Object
     Dim cmd As ADODB.Command, rs As ADODB.Recordset
     Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
     With cmd
         .ActiveConnection = dbconn
         .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM input_table ORDER BY Scenario"
         Set rs = .Execute
     End With
     
     Dim ar, arField, i As Long, f As String, scenario As String
     Dim class As String, yr As Long
     
     ' build data
     Do Until rs.EOF = True
        ' build struture for 1 scenario
        Dim dictClass
        Set dictClass = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Dim arYr(1 To 10)
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
           f = rs.Fields(i).Name
           'Debug.Print i, f
           If f = "Scenario" Then
               scenario = rs(i).Value
           ElseIf f Like "* ####" Then
               ' separate class, year, scenario from field name
               yr = Right(f, 4)
               class = Left(f, Len(f) - 5)
               'Debug.Print f, class, yr
               
               ' create class dictionary
               If Not dictClass.exists(class) Then
                   dictClass.Add class, arYr
               End If
               
               ' update array
               ar = dictClass(class)
               ar(yr - YR1 + 1) = rs(i).Value
               dictClass(class) = ar
           End If
        Next
        'Debug.Print scenario
        Set data(scenario) = dictClass

        ' Move to next Record
        rs.MoveNext
     Loop
     BuildCube = data

End Function

Function DbConnect(dbFile) As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sConn As String:
    sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
              & dbFile & ";Persist Security Info=False;"
    
    Set DbConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    DbConnect.Open sConn
End Function
```

Comment: Ok. I see. Thanks. This triggers the following question: As stated in my initial posting I used arrays in my first attempt. I accessed their content mostly via `worksheetfunction.match` or `worksheetfunction.index` etc. Then, I noticed that this is taking too much time. That's actually why I switched everything to dictionaries as this class helped me to avoid `worksheetfunction` as each key is unique. So is there a more elegant way to pull specific data from an array?

Comment: @art-i-fex What were you searching for in the array, some text ?

Comment: nope. I was searching for the numeric value that is behind the combination out of (1) scenario, (2) year and (3) class. the numeric value is a return rate.

Comment: @art-i-fex You access that directly using the array index or the dictionary key so fo my example the return rate for scenario 1 CLASS01 2023 would be data(scenario)(class)(yr-2022)  ie  `data(1)("CLASS01")(1)`. Of course this assumes your scenarios are numbered 1 to 2000.

Comment: Ok. That could be life changing. I will check and get back to you. Thank you very much for the moment.

Comment: I am stunned. That's amazing. Really! I mean it. Code now takes <5sec. Thank you! And, maybe even more valuable: I learned a lot from your code beyond the core purpose of pulling the data quickly. May I ask what class `data` is? And would you mind to give a brief qualitative summary of what your code is doing? To me it looks like the 3D array you mentioned above.

Comment: Oh yeah, I got that. But you are using `data(scenario)(class)(yr-2022)`. What is `data`?

Comment: @art-i-fex At the first level data is a 1-D array with 2000 elements, 1 for each scenario. Each element holds a dictionary with the fieldnames as keys, there will be 1 key for each asset class. The dictionary values hold a 10 element array with each element holding the rate for 1 year. data(scenario) will reference a dictionary, data(scenario)(class) will reference an array, and data(scenario)(class)(year-2022) will be the rate.

Comment: Worksheet functions aren't really "native" to VBA - when you use a worksheet function on an array, the array first needs to be bundled into a form that the calculation engine can work on, and that makes using worksheet functions with large arrays a *lot* slower than other VBA-only approaches such as just looping over the array.  Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031416/return-index-of-an-element-in-an-array-excel-vba/7031744#7031744

Comment: @CDP1802: I came across a follow-up question if I may. Yet, I managed to change one specific item within the array, however, is there a way to paste `data(scenario)(class)(year)` into a worksheet? With a normal array this could be simply done by `worksheet(name).cells = array`. Can that be done also with this nested array/dictionary?

Comment: @art-i-fex You can't dump that structure to a sheet without looping through it. You can dump the whole record set with `Sheets("Sheet name").range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs` see [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset)